# How can Windows 8 connect to a Mac OS X computer to computer network?

Tags: macos, windows-8, osx-mavericks

I set up a local computer-to-computer network on my MacBook Pro and had people test it by connecting. Everyone could connect with their laptops or desktops except for people running Windows 8. Their computer couldn’t even find the network. How can I fix this so Windows 8 computers can connect to my network?

Comment: This is not the widows support section  .

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, open up the Preference Panes, and then open Sharing.  Click on File Sharing, then on Options.  Make sure "Share files and folders using SMB" is checked.  You will also need to enable 1 or more accounts that can be used with Windows File Sharing (there's a long description about this in the Options window).

I don't see a "Guest" option, so you might need to create "windows-file-sharing" account on the Mac, enable that account in the Options window, and then give that username/password to your Windows users.